# credit report from Equifax in c#

Tags: c#, web-services

I want to know if it is possible to do credit report online, like calling a webservice. the only information I found is this post : http://wtcindia.wordpress.com/2010/08/01/credit-reporting-using-equifax/ but for Equifax in canada. Does anyone have already work with Equifax? I know that there's also System-to-System way of doing this but I have no idea of what this mean. Can someone explain me how you do system to system? I'm a Web developper and used to work with webservice and .net (more MVC but webforms too), I'm really confused and don't know where to search for exemple or explanation.

Thank you!

Comment: First of all you need to find out whether Equifax provide an interface for you to access their information - without this the question is purely academic.

Comment: "System to system" generally means a web service or API of some kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to let you know that is possible to send a XML request that will return a XML response with all the required information about the credit file. Your best bet is to contact them directly since all the informations is confidential.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of years ago I looked into this and the state of things then was that there was a way to work online with Equifax but rather than a regular web service you had to manually put together a POST request to a page they hosted and could then read the relevant response.

It was a pretty antiquated approach a few years back when I experimented with it so hopefully they have moved towards something a little bit more standard by now, but I wouldn't bet on it.

Either way it was certainly technically possible, just not a real pleasure to work with.

Comment: TransUnion was similar to this.  The response was pretty much just a text blob of a credit report, "formatted" with spaces.

Comment: Ok thanks guys, I think the system still use the same approach, guess it's possible. I already have contact them to have more informations and was looking for experiance from users over here.

Answer (score 0):

Creditsafe can provide you with a credit checking API that allows you to call information on an individual, business or company director. they hold data in almost 20 different countries so should be able to help with what you require.